# ListView não é exibida abaixo de um 'Container'

Tags: lista, listview, flutter, dart, widget

Sou novo no flutter e estou tendo dificuldades em exibir uma **ListView** abaixo de um **Container**. No treixo de códgo abaixo é exibido somente o meu **Container**, e a **ListView** simplesmente não aparece.
obs: não ocorre nenhum erro.

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado e como faço para que a lista seja exibida abaixo do meu Container.

Segue o meu código abaixo.

```
    class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  Widget _builderRow(WordPair pair){
    return Container(
      height: 120.0, // in logical pixels
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      // Row is a horizontal, linear layout.
      child: Row(
        // <Widget> is the type of items in the list.
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car_outlined),
            tooltip: 'Icon truck',
            onPressed: null, // null disables the button
          ),
          // Expanded expands its child to fill the available space.
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 50.0,
                width: 120.0,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text('Placa'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 120.0,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(pair.asString, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Mapa', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600)),
                      Text("321789456", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ]
                  )
                ),
                Text('Origem', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600)),
                Text("Pátio", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd)
            return Divider();
          /*2*/
          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
          }
          return _builderRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget _returnRoute() {
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Text("Carregamento", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0)),
          Text("Retorno de Rota", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          tooltip: 'Back',
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        title: Text('Manobrista'),
        actions: [Icon(Icons.search)],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            children: <Widget> [
              _returnRoute(),
              _buildSuggestions()
            ]
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: A _listView_ `_buildSuggestion` precisa possuir um _height_ fixo, pois como ela vai estar dentro de uma outra _ListView_ é causado um conflito de "desenho" entre elas.

Comment: Funcionou com a seguinte alteração

Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return Container(
        height: 610.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
    child: ListView.builder(...)
    );
}

Muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre pois seus widgets estão ordenados da seguinte maneira:

```
-ListView externa
- -> Alguns Texts
- -> ListView _buildSuggestions()
```

`Listview` é um Widget que permite o *scroll* de seu conteúdo. Dado que ele tem essa intenção, o seu conteúdo não é o suficiente para definir o seu tamanho.

Logo, quando você usa dois ListView's aninhados, fica indeterminado para o Flutter qual o tamanho que cada uma deve ter: A ListView mais externa permite tamanho infinito (para calcular e permitir o scroll que for necessário), enquanto que a interna não consegue calcular o tamanho que lhe é dado para dispor seu conteúdo.

Experimente, na [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) mais interna, utilizar a propriedade [ShrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) como true:

> Whether the extent of the scroll view in the scrollDirection should be determined by the contents being viewed.
>
> If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will expand to the maximum allowed size in the scrollDirection. If the scroll view has unbounded constraints in the scrollDirection, then shrinkWrap must be true.

Isto é, traduzindo, com essa propriedade verdadeira o tamanho dessa ListView será fornecido pelo conteúdo a ser visto. Caso esse scroll tenha altura ou largura ilimitados, essa propriedade deve ser marcada como `true`. Desta forma a ListView mais interna saberá o seu tamanho de ante-mão.

Aplicando em seu caso:

```
[...]
Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd)
            return Divider();
          /*2*/
          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
          }
          return _builderRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }
[...]
```

Comment: Realizei a alteração mas o mesmo exibe a tela toda branca.

Comment: Na documentação também diz que o `ShrinkWrap` toma um processamento maior do que apenas deixar a _ListView_ expandir no espaço que se tem disponível. No caso dele por ser uma lista de sugestões, é bom que ele mesmo sete um tamanho fixo para a _ListView_ interna.